# What jQuery version to mention in code

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery, and I'm little confused about what version is included at start of my page. From my experience with other software I understand that each new version contains most old features, and offers some new ones. If latests jQuery version is 1.9 for example, why would I mention this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../jqm145/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="../jq1-11-3/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="../jqm145/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

How do I check if a function will work in a specific version of Jquery?

Furthermore, the mobile JQuery version 1.4.5 and "plain" JQuery is 1.11.3. Why is this the case?

Comment: `*why mobile jQuery version in code is 1.4.5 and "plain" jQuery is 1.11.3*` - it is because they are 2 different files, which has its own versions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends from your target audience, and therefore from the browsers you need to support.
You have three options:

1. If you need to support older browsers like Internet Explorer 6-8,
   Opera 12.1x or Safari 5.1+, use: jQuery 1.11.3 + jQuery Mobile 1.4.5
2. If you need the current stable and most used pair, use: jQuery 2.1.4 + jQuery
   Mobile 1.4.5
3. If you are living on the edge, and would like to actively take part to the
   jQuery Mobile development, notify bugs and open issues on github,
   use: jQuery 3.2.1 + jQuery Mobile 1.5.0-alpha.1

Answer (score 1):

jQuery mobile (perhaps confusingly) is **not** a *mobile version of jQuery*, it's a library based on jQuery that contains controls, logic, etc. for Mobile devices.

jQuery has remained backwards compatible *until* version 3.0.0, in which support for older browsers has been dropped.

As a rule of thumb, it's good to update *both* libraries at the same time if one depends upon the other.

Comment: +1 with the little addition: to test if a function or a property exists in jQuery: `if(jQuery.nameOfTheFunction !== undefined){ /* the function exists */ }`. You can replace `jQuery` by `$` depending on your habits. To specifically test if it is a function, you can use `$.isFunction(myFunction)`

Comment: Thanks for additional explanation