# How to close a popup without close the whole page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

i need some helps. I am trying to make a video playlist and i make 2 html files (index.html and video.html). I try to play a video by popup in video.html, but when i close the popup or i click on everywhere, it's back to index.html directly. I link video.html from index.html though. How to close the popup without close the video.html. i can close the popup by the syntax that i use, but the problem is when i click on everywhere, video.html closes too, and it's back to index.html.
here is my video.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css"/>
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
   <title></title>
 
<script>
var vid = document.getElementById("video_mute");

vid.muted = true;//mute video on window load

function enableMute() { 
    vid.muted = true;
} 

function disableMute() { 
    vid.muted = false;
} 

function checkMute() { 
    alert(vid.muted);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="satu">  
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>abjad</h1></div>
    <div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview">
   <li><a href="#a" data-rel="popup" data-transition="pop">huruf A</a></li>
   <li><a href="#b" data-rel="popup" data-transition="pop">huruf b</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
 <div data-role="footer">footer</div>
  
 <div data-role="popup" data-position-to="window" id="a">
  <video width="block" id="video_mute" controls>
   <source src="abjad_a.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <button onclick="enableMute()" type="button">Mute sound</button>
   <button onclick="disableMute()" type="button">Enable sound</button>
   <button onclick="checkMute()" type="button">Check muted status</button><br>
   </video>
   
 </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: use `data-dismissible="false"` here is the reference documentation: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/popup/ - check the example of the `Dialog` paragraph in this page. BTW, you should update your jQuery and JQM versions to the latest stable: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44910517/4845566

Answer (score -2):

> - you can use **data-dismiss** attibute to close a pop-up.
> - or you also use jquery to dismiss popup.
>
> > ```
> > $("#popup-id").modal("hide");
> > ```

Comment: i tried it, but it doesn't work. is there any way? please help me.

Comment: if you couldn't find any solution. i would suggest that you add a wrapper div the wraps all the code of your Dialog, and set the display property to "none" using javascript.