# jQuery mobile Header and Footer not showing up at all

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I had to do an assignment for class and for some reason I couldn't get jQuery Mobile to work. I wrote everything as my professor told us to, but it still wouldn't show up. There is supposed to be a jQuery Mobile header and footer, that stays on screen at all time while scrolling, but it doesn't show up. Here's all the relevant code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Homework 2</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    var key = "";
    var URL = "";
    var zip = "";
    var weather = 0;

    //sets the sip variable to the given zipcode
    function setZip(temp) {
        zip = temp;
    }

    //sets the weather variable to the given object
    function setWeather(temp) {
        weather = temp;
    }

    //generates and displays hourly weather
    function generateContent() {

        //resets the div element, so the previous content is replaced, and not built upon
        document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML = "";

        key = document.getElementById("key").value;
        URL = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/" + key + "/geolookup/q/autoip.json";

        //used to locate the zipcode value
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: URL,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (msg) {

                if (msg.response.error == undefined)
                    setZip(msg.location.zip);
                else {
                    alert("Error");
                    return;
                }
            },
            error: function (jgXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error: " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
                return;
            }
        });

        URL = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/" + key + "/hourly/q/" + zip + ".json"

        //used to get the json hourly weather object that will be used for displaying the hourly weather
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: URL,
            data: {},
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (msg) {

                setWeather(msg.hourly_forecast);

            },
            error: function (jgXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error: " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
                return;
            }
        });

        //for loop that cycles through all weather elements, and displays their time, date, and the icon for the weather
        for (var i = 0; i < weather.length; i++) {

            var time = weather[i].FCTTIME.hour_padded;
            var timeZone = weather[i].FCTTIME.tz;
            var date = weather[i].FCTTIME.month_name + " " + weather[i].FCTTIME.mday + ", " + weather[i].FCTTIME.year;
            //var icon = weather[i].icon + "<img src='" + obj[i].icon_url + "' alt='icon'>

            var text = time + ":00" + " " + timeZone + " on " + date + " ";

            var icon = document.createElement("img");
            icon.src = weather[i].icon_url;

            //used to append created elements onto the empty div element 
            var paragraph = document.createElement("p").appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
            document.getElementById("contents").appendChild(paragraph);
            document.getElementById("contents").appendChild(icon);
            document.getElementById("contents").appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        }

    }
    </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"><h1>Assignment 2</h1></div>
        <div data-role="content"> 
            <p>Input Wunderground key to see the hourly weather in your area.</p>
               <input id="key" type="text" />
               <br />
                <button onclick="generateContent()">Get the Weather!</button>
                <br /> <br />
                <div id="contents"></div> <br />
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"><h1>CS275</h1></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know if there's anything missing from the code, cause I honestly can't see what's wrong, though I'll be honest, I'm not exactly that great at web development so far, so I'm probably just missing something very simple here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you provide the missing JavaScript part? From what I can see my bet is that it should be some error in the js code. Do you see any errors if you open the browser dev tools?

Comment: Ok, I just added it in, there's an error that comes up in the file jquery.mobile.js on the line "mouseEventProps = $.event.props.concat( mouseHookProps )," with the error saying "cannot read property of undefined at... " then it brings up several lines from the file jquery.mobile.min.js

Comment: Try adding defer to the script tag, like this `<script defer>`. My guess is the code is failing because is running before the HTML body is loaded.

Comment: To which script tag, all of them? or just the jquery mobile one?

Comment: Just the one containing your code.

Comment: It didn't seem to do anything

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What jQuery version to mention in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44907336/what-jquery-version-to-mention-in-code)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I was including the wrong links at the top below the meta tag. I should have instead included:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js">
</script>
```