# JQuery Mobile - version conflicts, radiobutton JS refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, radio-button, compatibility

I am getting back to developing with JQueryMobile, which proves fabulous for prototyping mobile apps, but there is a potential version issue I have bumped into: 
either the formatting works fine but js-checked radiobuttons do not refresh, or the formatting needs to go out of the window and then the same JS does manage to produce the refresh.I am working on dreamweaver CS6 and cross-checking with js-bin.

Here is the page with working JQM formatting, but the lack of radiobutton self-update functionality. 
http://jsfiddle.net/tearex/bh9szuer/

```
    <head> 
    <title>My Page</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body ONLOAD="heja()"> 

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">    
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    <legend>Choose a pet:</legend>
         <input class="group1" type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="WTEDY_0" value="choice-1" />
         <label for="WTEDY_0">Cat</label>

         <input class="group1" type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="WTEDY_1" value="choice-2"   />
         <label for="WTEDY_1">Dog</label>
</fieldset>
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->

</body>

<script>
function heja()
{

document.getElementById("WTEDY_0").checked = true;


        $("WTEDY_0").checkboxradio("refresh");

}
</script>
```

Not sure if the checked status is updated but there is no refresh.

Here is a page with the most recent jqm - and it is not showing jqm formatting at all (the way, this is the case with the page being loaded into chrome, too - up-to-date, on windows 7 64 bit) 
http://jsfiddle.net/tearex/bh9szuer/2/

```
    <head> 
    <title>My Page</title> 

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/my-custom-theme.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" /> 
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script> 
</head> 
<body ONLOAD="heja()"> 

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">    
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    <legend>Choose a pet:</legend>
         <input class="group1" type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="WTEDY_0" value="choice-1" />
         <label for="WTEDY_0">Cat</label>

         <input class="group1" type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="WTEDY_1" value="choice-2"   />
         <label for="WTEDY_1">Dog</label>
</fieldset>
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->

</body>

<script>
function heja()
{

document.getElementById("WTEDY_0").checked = true;


        $("WTEDY_0").checkboxradio("refresh");

}
</script>
```

And here is the page making no reference to css at all, and the onload function works properly. 
http://jsfiddle.net/tearex/y4a369ps/1/

```
    <head> 
    <title>My Page</title> 

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head> 
<body ONLOAD="heja()"> 

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">    
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    <legend>Choose a pet:</legend>
         <input class="group1" type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="WTEDY_0" value="choice-1" />
         <label for="WTEDY_0">Cat</label>

         <input class="group1" type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="WTEDY_1" value="choice-2"   />
         <label for="WTEDY_1">Dog</label>
</fieldset>
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
<script>
function heja()
{

document.getElementById("WTEDY_0").checked = true;


        $("WTEDY_0").checkboxradio("refresh");

}
</script>
```

I have some questions. 
    1. How to achieve the radiobutton status change and refresh and retain JQM?
    2. Which version of jqm do you find optimal, or - ideally - how do you make the latest one work?
    3. Side question what is the recommended most compatible web-based jsfiddle equivalent? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have found the answer to the JQM conflict with body onload - this has to do with the order in which JQM executed relative to <body>.  A workaround is to replace the function with "unwrapped" JS instructions (http://jsfiddle.net/tearex/784u21do/2/) or to have the function triggered by some user activity. What remains as questions is which is the most universally compatible  - and working - jqm version. I look forward to the answers. Thanks.

Comment: Please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44910517/4845566  and here: [jQuery Mobile “Page” Events – What, Why, Where, When & How?](https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/)

Answer (score 1):

It is time to switch to *https*:

```
<!-- JQM theme shall be loaded before structure -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/my-custom-theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/my-custom-styles.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
    /* my custom settings */
  });
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js">
<script src="js/my-custom-functions.js">
```

Regarding the refresh, please also don't forget that jQuery need the CSS-style selector:

```
function heja() {
  var id = 'WTEDY_0', el = document.getElementById(id);
  el.checked = true; 
  $('#' + id).prop('checked', true); /* The jQuery way */
  var isInstance = $.data(el, 'mobile-checkboxradio');
  if(isInstance) {
    $('#' + id).checkboxradio('refresh'); /* The JQM Widgets way */
  }
}
```

Here is a working example on Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/yLEB2XFlM8H4cqsZ?open=lib%2Fscript.js